# Error al generar archivo .pem con OpenSSL

Tags: php, linux, openssl

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente comando para generar mi archivo .pem

```
$commandLinux = 'openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -outform PEM -in '.$ruta_key.' -passin pass:'.$password.' -out '.$ruta_key_PEM;
$response= shell_exec($commandLinux);
```

Pero me da `error:06065064` he investigado y al parecer es por la versión de OpenSSL por que ya verifique que todos los datos sean correctos. La versión que estoy usando es la OpenSSL 1.1.1g 21 Apr 2020. Alguien que me pudiera dar una idea de que tengo mal??

Comment: Por favor, incluye el mensaje de error completo. Dependiendo de la situación, ese error se puede deber a que a) tu certificado (`$ruta_key`) debe ser regenerado porque expiró, o b) la clave para la llave privada es incorrecta

Comment: Error decrypting key 140191095608448:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:583: 140191095608448:error:23077074:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_pbe_crypt:pkcs12 cipherfinal error:../crypto/pkcs12/p12_decr.c:63: 140191095608448:error:2306A075:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_item_decrypt_d2i:pkcs12 pbe crypt error:../crypto/pkcs12/p12_decr.c:94:

Este es el mensaje de error completo, verifique los certificados y la key en la página del SAT y son correctos